# Elasticsearch exact match field

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a field called `url` that is set to `not_analyzed` when I index it:

```
'url' => [
    'type' => 'string',
    'index' => 'not_analyzed'
]
```

Here is my method to determine if a URL already exists in the index:

```
public function urlExists($index, $type, $url) {
    $params = [
        'index' => $index,
        'type' => $type,
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'match' => [
                    'url' => $url
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $results = $this->client->count($params);

    return ($results['count'] > 0);
}
```

This seems to work fine however I can't be 100% sure this is the correct way to find an exact match, as reading the docs another way to do the search is with the params like:

```
    $params = [
        'index' => $index,
        'type' => $type,
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'filtered' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        'term' => [
                            'url' => $url
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

My question is would either params work the same way for a `not_analyzed` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query is the right approach. `term level queries/filters` should be used for exact match. Biggest advantage is [caching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-caching.html). `Elasticsearch` uses [bitset](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html#_internal_filter_operation) for this and you will get quicker response time with subsequent calls.

From the Docs

> Exclude as many document as you can with a filter, then query just the
>   documents that remain.

Also if you observe your output, you will find that `_score` of every document is **1** as scoring is not applied to filters, same goes for highlighting but with match query you will see different `_score`. Again From the Docs

> Keep in mind that once you wrap a query as a filter, it loses query
>   features like highlighting and scoring because these are not features
>   supported by filters.

Your first query uses `match` which is basically used for `analyzed fields` e.g when you want both *Google* and *google* to match all your documents containing google(case insensitive) `match queries` are used.

Hope this helps!!